# I can't add Image to a JButton in Java

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;


public class Gui extends JFrame{


private JButton normal;
private JButton custom;

public Gui(){
    super("button program");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    Icon b=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("C:\\temp\\image\\b.jpg"));

    custom=new JButton("custom",b);
    add(custom);
}
}
```

and I got this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at javax.swing.ImageIcon.(Unknown Source)
>   at Gui.(Gui.java:22)
>   at test.main(test.java:7)

I tried putting image in src, doesn't work too.

Comment: Yeah    Iconb=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("C:\\temp\\image\\b.jpg"));
 points to nothing, no variable in that class atleast. Thats what the NullPointerException means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot load external files like 'C:\test\image\b.jpg' by using `getClass().getResource(...)`.

But ImageIcon as a nice constructor that loads an image from is path.
Use something like this instead:

```
Icon b = new ImageIcon("C:\\temp\\image\\b.jpg");
```

Comment: OMG. That took my whole day. but then, what is the differance between    Icon b = new ImageIcon("C:\\temp\\image\\b.jpg"); and Icon b=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("C:\\temp\\image\\b.jpg"));    (and sorry cant use this site properly)  and thank you

Comment: @EkremSolmaz See http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/2433/resources-on-classpath#t=201701111734535687024&a=remarks .  A resource is data packaged inside the application, where it may or may not be a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

You can cerate pakage in application and store icon to this package com.icon

example for add icon to jbutton:

```
button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(MyFrame.class.getResource("com/icon/Ok.png")));
```